# how would i have 1 section open at any time

Tags: jquery, css

I followed this https://arthemes.org/blog/toggle-fields-group-on-the-classipress-listing-form/?unapproved=209&moderation-hash=960dba8a3f7ad0b66995e1d616f30397#comment-209 tutorial which worked fine for 1 button

I needed 5 buttons and after some hit and miss have it functioning but not excactly as required.  I have 5 buttons stacked horizontal, when any button is clicked the content is shown after the last button rather than its own button. I also require only one item open at a time to keep the form clean.

```js
/* button 1*/

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#list__cp_address').each(function() {
    var collapsed = $(this).nextUntil('#list_cp_females_available', '.form-field');

    if (collapsed.length < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    collapsed.wrapAll('<div id="moreFieldsWrapper" class="hidden"></div>');
    $(this).after('<div id="for_sale_end_off_puppy_section"><div class="form-field"><a class="my_message_button" id="moreFieldsToggle" href="#">Add Puppy Info</a></div></div>');
  });
  $('#moreFieldsToggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#moreFieldsWrapper').toggle();
  });
});


/* button 2 starts here*/

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#for_sale_end_off_puppy_section').each(function() {
    var collapsed = $(this).nextUntil('#list_cp_sire', '.form-field');

    if (collapsed.length < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    collapsed.wrapAll('<div id="moreFieldsWrapper1" class="hidden"></div>');
    $(this).after('<div id="for_sale_end_off_availabilty"><div class="form-field1"><a class="my_message_button" id="moreFieldsToggle1" href="#">Add Pups Available</a></div></div>');
  });
  $('#moreFieldsToggle1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#moreFieldsWrapper1').toggle();
  });
});

/* button 3 starts here*/

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#for_sale_end_off_availabilty').each(function() {
    var collapsed = $(this).nextUntil('#list_cp_dam', '.form-field');

    if (collapsed.length < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    collapsed.wrapAll('<div id="moreFieldsWrapper2" class="hidden"></div>');
    $(this).after('<div id="for_sale_end_off_sire"><div class="form-field2"><a class="my_message_button" id="moreFieldsToggle2" href="#">Add Sire Info</a></div></div>');
  });
  $('#moreFieldsToggle2').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#moreFieldsWrapper2').toggle();
  });
});

/* button 4 starts here*/

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#for_sale_end_off_sire').each(function() {
    var collapsed = $(this).nextUntil('#list_cp_ecpm_video_1', '.form-field');

    if (collapsed.length < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    collapsed.wrapAll('<div id="moreFieldsWrapper3" class="hidden"></div>');
    $(this).after('<div id="for_sale_end_off_dam"><div class="form-field3"><a class="my_message_button" id="moreFieldsToggle3" href="#">Add Dam Info</a></div></div>');
  });
  $('#moreFieldsToggle3').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#moreFieldsWrapper3').toggle();
  });
});

/* button 5 starts here*/

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#for_sale_end_off_dam').each(function() {
    var collapsed = $(this).nextUntil('#list_post_content', '.form-field');

    if (collapsed.length < 1) {
      return false;
    }
    collapsed.wrapAll('<div id="moreFieldsWrapper4" class="hidden"></div>');
    $(this).after('<div id="for_sale_end_add_video"><div class="form-field4"><a class="my_message_button" id="moreFieldsToggle4" href="#">Add A Video</a></div></div>');
  });
  $('#moreFieldsToggle4').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#moreFieldsWrapper4').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
a.my_message_button {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #1e93be !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 16px
}

a.my_message_button:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #27aada !important;
}

a.btn-group {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* Green border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px;
  /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
  width: 20% !important;
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

a.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table !important;
}

a.btn-group:not(:last-child) {
  border-radius: 50px/* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

a.btn-group:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.moreFieldsWrapper {
  display: none;
}

.moreFieldsWrapper1 {
  display: none;
}

.moreFieldsWrapper2 {
  display: none;
}

.moreFieldsWrapper3 {
  display: none;
}

.moreFieldsWrapper4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add RELEVANT HTML to it to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also DRY - don't repeat yourself. Have ONE function handle all buttons - either delegate or pass the button selector to the function

Comment: And, while we are making code suggestions: don't add HTML as a string. It's much simpler to show and hide elements by adding and removing a CSS class that hides the element. See: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: mplungjan thank you , i will have to try and learn how to get the relevant html and post it .thankyou